# Javascript: extract objects from inside an array of objects, and put them into a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Say I had

```
var people =[{name:"Jim", address:{number:"21",street:"park lane"}},
{name:"Karen",address:{number:"35", street:"oxford drive"}},
{name:"Bob",address:{number:65, street:"main avenue"}}]
```

and I wanted to get an array of just the address objects, is there a shorthand way?

I know I could just iterate over the people array and push the addresses onto a new array, but I imagine there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
people.map(function(x){return x.address;});
```

You are still iterating, but it is more concise.